# Adding mailto: link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to `.append` a simple **Website by John Bob** in the footer of a website. However, I need the name **John Bob** to be a `mailto:` link. This has to be done with jQuery.

Here is what I have so far, but it's not working for me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var e = "mailto:jbob@live.com";
  $("footer .copyright").append("<div> Website by <a href="" + $(e) + "" target='_top'>John Bob</a></div>");
});
```

Comment: The answer is correct but just to point out, after your href=" you should not have put another set of double quotes. You used single quotes for target so you should have done the same for e. I don't know much about function($) so I can't comment on it, but quotes for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var e = "mailto:jbob@live.com";
    $("footer .copyright").append('<div> Website by <a href="' + e + '" target="_top">John Bob</a></div>');
});
```

Pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting & clean approach is to use [chaining](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2007/10/26/jQuery-Understanding-the-chain).

```
$("<a target='_top'>")
  .text("John Bob")
  .attr("href", "mailto:jbob@live.com")
  .appendTo("<div>Website by </div>")
  .parent()
  .appendTo("footer .copyright")
  .end();
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6ptc3d8u/1/